# JExcel API : how to change the color of a Cell?

Tags: java, excel, jxl

I search how to change the color of a cell, selected in a Excel file.
I tested this code :

```
    WritableCell c = sheet.getWritableCell(0,0);
    WritableCellFormat newFormat = new WritableCellFormat(c.getCellFormat());
    newFormat.setBackground(Colour.RED);
    c.setCellFormat(newFormat);
```

But this example doesn't run.
What is the solution ?

Answer (score 3):

check this out
you may did not use  write(); and  close(); methods

```
Workbook wk= Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("ex.xls"));

WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("modifed.xls"), wk);

WritableSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);

WritableCell c = sheet.getWritableCell(0,0);

WritableCellFormat newFormat = new WritableCellFormat();

newFormat.setBackground(Colour.RED);

c.setCellFormat(newFormat);



workbook.write(); // important to use
workbook.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

For Android version of lib:

```
Label label = new Label(5, 5, "Ohh May");
WritableCellFormat newFormat = new WritableCellFormat();

newFormat.setBackground(Colour.RED);
label.setCellFormat(newFormat);
sheet.addCell(label);
```